# Updating a column based on conditions

Tags: plsql

I have a table like:

```
ID  ID2 Name
1   1   
2   1   
3   2   
4   2   
5   2   
6   3   
7   3   
8   3
```

I want to Update the Name column with Values like Name1, name 2 and so on.
This will be based on condition if there are two similar values in ID2 column, for example, the first two rows, then the Name column to be updated with values Name1 and Name2 respectively.Next rows would be Name1, Name2, Name3 respectively and so on. Can someone help me with the logic for this?

Comment: What have you already tried? Provide some code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER` with a partition on the `ID2` column, ordered by the `ID` column, should generate the sequences you want.  Try this update query:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET Name = (SELECT 'Name' || t.rn FROM
               (
                   SELECT t2.ID, t2.ID2,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ID2 ORDER BY t2.ID) rn
                   FROM yourTable t2
                   WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.ID2 = t2.ID2
               ) t)
```